# Defining extended entities in sonata

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony4

I have some base entity that defines some fields which all (or at least most of) other entities should have. It looks like:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
abstract class BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $published;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updatedAt;



    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
```

and so on...getters and setters.

Then I have entity i.e. ArticleCategory extending that BaseEntity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleCategoryRepository")
 */
class ArticleCategory extends BaseEntity
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

So, it's just adding one extra field - title.

Then, I have base admin class:

```
namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use App\Entity\BaseEntity;

class BaseAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

    /**
     * @param BaseEntity $entity
     */
    public function prePersist($entity)
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $entity->setCreatedAt($now);
        $entity->setUpdatedAt($now);
        $entity->setPublished(true);
    }
}
```

And then admin class for that ArticleCategory entity:

```
namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

final class ArticleCategoryAdmin extends BaseAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('title', TextType::class);
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('title');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('title');
    }
}
```

Problem is when I go to sonata list page instead of displaying all entities in ArticleCategory type I get an sql error:

**Unknown column 'b0_.id' in 'field list'**

And query looks like this:

```
SELECT b0_.id AS id_0, b0_.published AS published_1, b0_.created_at AS created_at_2, b0_.updated_at AS updated_at_3, a1_.title AS title_4 
FROM article_category a1_ 
WHERE a1_.id IN (?, ?) 
ORDER BY a1_.id ASC' with params [2, 3]
```

So sonata is getting data from correct table (article_category) and making an alias for it "a1_" and all fields that are directly inside ArticleCategory (title) are collected well, with that alias.
But all other fields that belong to base class (BaseEntity) sonata is trying to get via some un-existing alias "b0_" and query fails of course.

Any idea how to solve this? How to tell sonata that all the fields belong to the same table even they belong to 2 entity classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. At the beginning where base entity was defined I had:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
```

Which is not correct because of that "Entity()" row. That had to be removed. It can't be entity and mapped supper class at the same time.

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
```